# Flag value is not getting changed in Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I am very new to shell scripts and I have a basic image resizing script:

```
#!/bin/bash

isResizeAnotherImage=Y;
for isResizeAnotherImage in Y y N n
do
  echo "option entered before if: $isResizeAnotherImage";
  if [ $isResizeAnotherImage='Y' ] || [ $isResizeAnotherImage='y' ]; then
    echo "Enter the file name :  ";
    read imageFileName;
    read -p "Enter desired size:  " imageDesiredSize;
    mogrify -resize $imageDesiredSize $imageFileName 2>/dev/null;

    echo "Resize another image ? Y/N : ";
    read isResizeAnotherImage;
    echo "option entered in if: $isResizeAnotherImage";
  else
    echo "option entered : $isResizeAnotherImage";
    exit 1;
  fi;
done
```

Now, It resizes first image successfully, asks 'Resize another image?'. Here, I enter 'N'. But in the next loop, it shows that the value of flag has not been changed to 'N'. So it enters the if condition. 
Why is this happening and how to prevent it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indenting is a bit off which makes it hard to read your code.

Ignoring that, what is your for-loop for? Is that supposed to be a while-loop? As I see it this is going to make your variable isResizeAnotherImage take the values YyNn and ignore what you have entered at the prompt. Change your for-loop to a while-loop and I suspect it will work.

Comment: Oh I still lack the concept of for loop in shell script. Thank you very much for guiding me to the right direction. Yes that is supposed to be a while loop and I will do that right now.

Comment: Yes that worked. Is there any kind of breakpoints in shell scripts ? they make coding as well as debugging very easy.

Comment: Add the -x option to the first line in your script to make it :#!/bin/bash -x   This will start the shell in debug mode and it will give a lot of verbose output. It's not debugging in the sense that you can step through the code but it is often enough to get a feel for what is going on. I'm sure others have probably asked the same question on this site